# Select query returns false result

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, select

eg:

Table : `user`

column : `user_id` (type is int)

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '10xyz'
```

is giving same result of

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '10'
```

The input value is not integer but not giving an error in this case.

Answer (score 10):

The reason why you are getting the same result is because `MySQL` automatically *removes the  trailing characters* from the string and *implicitly converts* it to integer.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cfef/5)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*updated*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cfef/20)

Comment: @sgeddes right, i hate mysql for being implicit! hehe try this also `UPDATE tableName SET col2 = 2 AND col = 4`

Comment: Is there a way to catch this condition. I don't need the result in this case.

Comment: @Tom `BINARY`, *I guess*. [**>>CLICK_HERE<<**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cfef/18)

Comment: @ JW : Thanks JW. I have tried SELECT * FROM USER WHERE BINARY RowID = '10xyz'; which is also fine. But in our existing code we have to modify the code by checking the type. That will be a huge process and right now that is not possible. Is there any smarter solution by setting any configuration

Comment: @Tom sorry, i'm not thrilled of altering configurations. But another suggestion is to convert the datatype of column `user_id` to string because in string, `10 <> 10xxx`

Comment: @JW : user_id is our primary key. so type changing is not possible. :-(

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change all your code, but you have your database queries all going through one or a few subs, you can change those to check for warnings after using a statement handle (e.g. `if ( $sth->{mysql_warning_count} ) ...`).

Or you can create a DBI subclass that does that automatically for you, promoting warnings to errors.  If you do, many others have use for such a thing.  There are configuration settings to give an error instead of a warning when updating or inserting something like '10xyz' into an integer field, but not anything broader than that, and dear Oracle considers it [Not a Bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50757).  Maybe MariaDB does (or could do) better?

Answer (score 1):

datatype of user_id is in database is INT

that why it giving same output and not error

Comment: Actually I don't want the result in this case. Can I catch this as error? Or no result should come in this particular case.